# Composer vendor installing in another vendor folder

Tags: php, composer-php

Let's say I have two packages `package` and `package-extensions`. So let's say `package` upon install, goes to `/vendor/package/src`. This package will have something like `/vendor/package/src/replace.php`.

Next, I want to install `package-extensions` such that it replaces `/vendor/package/src/replace.php` file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't, but you can add to the `composer.json` a **post-install event script** to do it.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#installer-events

*Unfortunately*, you'll have to add the post-install script in the `compsoser.json` **of the project** using `package` and `package-extension`. It won't work if you add the script in the `composer.json` of `package-extension` because composer doesn't run the event scripts of the dependencies.